# std::add_const, why the implementation works for reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

In cppreference [`add_const`](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/boi2016/doc/cppreference/reference/en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_cv.html) it is said we may implement it as:

```
template< class T> struct add_const { typedef const T type; };
```

When I try a reference type, like `std::add_const<int&>`， it is `int&`.

My question is why it can work without a specific version for reference, since `int& const` is illegal？

Comment: `int& const` is illegal only when used explicitly, while extra const is simply ignored in other contexts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [dcl.ref]p1 of the C++11 standard, you can find:

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef (7.1.3) or of a template type argument (14.3), in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored.